# Como puedo hacer una api con php que reciba por get y responda con un json

Tags: php, json, webservice

Quiero hacer un webservice con php que Reciba por get un usuario y contraseña y con ello consultar en la base de datos y en caso de encontrarlo retorne un json con los datos del usuario como estatura, peso, nacionalidad, etc. y en el php que uso como cliente reciba ese json para mostrar los datos.

Algo así:

**cliente.php ----> https://servidorejemplo/api.php?usuario=ejemplouser&sontrasenia=contraejemplo**

**api.php----> (json con los datos del usuario) ----> cliente.php**

Estoy haciendo pruebas de momento con mi cliente:

```
$i=file_get_contents("https://server/carpeta/api.php?a=hola");
$res=json_decode($i,TRUE);
echo $res;
```

Y con mi api:

```
$ha="RESPUESTA Y TE REGRESO EL GET -->".$_GET['a'];
$response['variable']=$ha;
$jsonresponse=json_encode($response);
echo $jsonresponse;
```

Comment: Que te impide hacerlo? Que has intentado?

Comment: Uso file_get_contents y la url, en el php de la api tengo return json pero en mi php de cliente no recibe o pareciera que no recibe

Comment: si coloco un echo en mi api e imprimo la variable que recibe el  file_get_contents en realidad lo que hace es tomar el codigo de la api y ejecutarlo en mi código, pero no está recibiendo una respuesta

Comment: No entendi. Si quieres edita tu pregunta y agrega la parte de codigo de la api y la parte de código desde donde llamas la api

Comment: No uses **nunca** [GET para enviar contraseñas](https://geoestrategia.webnode.es/news/vulnerabilidades-de-aplicaciones-web-envio-de-contrasena-usando-el-metodo-get/), es un pésima idea.

Comment: Como puedo retornar un json con los datos y como lo recibo en el php cliente?